# All permutations of a relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm not understanding how I can return all available configurations of a relationship. It's probably easy but I just can't wrap my head around it.

For example, given:

e.g

```
CREATE (:STARTER{name: 'start'}), (:ENDER{name: 'end'})
CREATE (:Upstream{name: 'A'}), (:Upstream {name: 'B'}), (:Upstream {name: 'C'})
CREATE (:Downstream {name: '1'}),(:Downstream {name: '2'}),(:Downstream {name: '3'})

MATCH(s:STARTER), (u:Upstream)
CREATE (s)-[:owns]->(u)

MATCH(e:ENDER), (d:Downstream)
CREATE (e)-[:owns]->(d)

MATCH(a:Upstream {name: 'A'}), (d:Downstream)
CREATE (a)-[:related]->(d)

MATCH(b:Upstream {name: 'B'}), (d:Downstream)
CREATE (b)-[:related]->(d)

MATCH(c:Upstream {name: 'C'}), (d:Downstream)
CREATE (c)-[:related]->(d)
```

I want to return the ALL configurations available to the downstream nodes from the upstream nodes if they are related (they're all related in the example provided for ease)

In this example DOWNSTREAM 1,2 and 3 must always be used. The return would look like related

```
Downstream 1 | Downstream 2 | Downstream 3
__________________________________________
Upstream A   | Upstream A   | Upstream A
Upstream A   | Upstream A   | Upstream B
Upstream A   | Upstream A   | Upstream C
Upstream A   | Upstream B   | Upstream A
Upstream A   | Upstream B   | Upstream B
Upstream A   | Upstream B   | Upstream C
Upstream A   | Upstream C   | Upstream A
Upstream A   | Upstream C   | Upstream B
Upstream A   | Upstream C   | Upstream C
Upstream B   | Upstream A   | Upstream A
....
Upstream C   | Upstream C   | Upstream C
```

I've started with:

```
MATCH (s:STARTER)-[:owns]->(u:Upstream)
WITH s, u
MATCH (e:ENDER)-[:owns]->(d:Downstream)<-[:related]-(u)
```

But to be honest I have no idea what to do next. Can anyone offer insight?

Edit: Thanks to @Dom Weldon because I forgot the name of this. I'm looking for the Cartesian Product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Columns (variables) in Neo4j can't be dynamic to my knowledge, so you have to be explicit.

Would something like this work?

```
MATCH (:Downstream{name:'1'})<-[:related]-(u1)
MATCH (:Downstream{name:'2'})<-[:related]-(u2)
MATCH (:Downstream{name:'3'})<-[:related]-(u3)
RETURN u1, u2, u3
ORDER BY u1.name, u2.name, u3.name
```

You can alias the columns as you need, but u1 will correspond to upstream nodes from :Downstream 1, and so on for 2 and 3.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll try as soon as and let you know

Comment: It's a nice idea but relies on the face I know the names of the Downstreams I'm querying on. I'm looking for a more generic method  e.g. MATCH (:Downstream)<-[:related]-(u). If I find it I'll post it. Thanks again.

Comment: While not the answer I hoped for, I've ended up querying for Downstreams and then creating a query string on the fly based on the above answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite clear precisely what you're looking for here, since I'm not sure what the combinations referred to in the table are, however, it sounds like what you're looking for is a way to find all paths between two nodes. To do that you would run the following query.

```
MATCH p=((s:STARTER{name: 'start'})-[:owns|related]-(e:ENDER{name: 'end'}))
RETURN p
```

That should give you what you're looking for. Otherwise you may be looking to build a Cartesian product, which is not too common a use case for a graph database.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I am looking for the Cartesian product - I went blank on the name.

Comment: I see, so just to be clear - what do the columns 1, 2, and 3 mean in your output table?

Comment: They are the names of the Downstream nodes. Apologies - I could have been clearer. I thought I was keeping it simple but perhaps just made it confusing....

Comment: To try to clarify, I always have to have an upstream node mapped to all three of (Downstream{name:'1'}), (Downstream{name:'2'})
 and (Downstream{name:'3'}).

I can use any of the related upstream nodes to fulfil that contract. I can use 1 = (Upstream{name:'A'}),  2= (Upstream{name:'A'}), 3=
 (Upstream{name:'A'})
Or 
1 = (Upstream{name:'A'}),  2= (Upstream{name:'A'}), 3=
 (Upstream{name:'B'})

and so on down the table. That'll be a Cartesian product of sorts I think - all Upstream permutations available to (Downstream{name:'1'}), (Downstream{name:'2'})
 and (Downstream{name:'3'})..